# A very different alternative form of the geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

While I was playing around with series that came up in a calculus assignment I came across this thing here:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[x]{n^{x-1}i}}$$
And after using wolframalpha to evaluate it at some positive real numbers $x$ it seems that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[x]{n^{x-1}i}} = \frac{x}{x-1}$$
which is the value of the geometric series with parameter $\frac{1}{x}$. Unfortunately I have no clue how to prove this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[x]{n^{x-1}k}} = $$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n (n^{x-1}k)^{-\frac{1}{x}} = $$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-\frac{1}{x}} = $$

$$\int_{0}^1t^{-\frac{1}{x}}dt = \frac{x}{x-1} $$

Comment: Nobody wants to look for the place where you messed up. Fix it, or delete it.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Well, I can't find it. I'm not sure if OP's result was correct or if I made an error.

Comment: Your downvotes are your problem.

Comment: The OP had the result from Wolfram Alpha, so you argue with them.

Comment: @orlp could you explain how you got the integral? up to that point everything seems to be correct

Comment: @ProfessorVector I found the sign error.

Comment: Ok, I revoked the downvote.

Comment: @LeaW It's the [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Comment: @orlp thank you very much! :)